# What is the connection string to use Azure Storage Emulator with a Webjob?

Tags: azure, connection-string, azure-webjobs

I have a simple WebJob which I wish to test with the Azure Storage Emulator.

I currently have set the AzureJobsRuntime and AzureJobsData set to use development storage as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AzureJobsRuntime" connectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true;" />
    <add name="AzureJobsData" connectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The webjob is very simple:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    JobHost host = new JobHost();
    host.RunAndBlock();
}

public static void Process([QueueInput("queue")] string input, [BlobOutput("containername/blobname")]TextWriter writer)
{

}
```

This throws an exception on startup:

InvalidOperationException:

Windows Azure Storage account connection string is not formatted correctly

I have been able to create the queue and add messages to it from a website using the same connection string and the `CloudStorageAccount` class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately the WebJobs SDK does not support using Azure storage emulator as some features it uses are not supported by this emulator.

Comment: Also worth noting that the 2.2.1 preview emulator did not work either. An error message was kicked out that development storage was not supported.

Comment: @amit-apple Does the WebJobs SDK support the 3.0 storage emulator?

Comment: Still not supported WAS 3.2 . I hope that this will change soon.

Comment: @Amit does that mean that there is no way to test web jobs locally on my development machine? I have to deploy in order to test?

Comment: @Jack If you mean WebJobs using the WebJobs SDK, then you can test them locally by simply pointing to the production Azure storage (could be a different storage account/container/table) instead of to an emulator, it's not the best solution and requires internet connection but it works.

Comment: Its pretty ridiculous running locally is not properly supported. plugging it into live azure != development support

Comment: I'm also frustrated that the Azure SDK isn't allowing me to use my locally defined Queues as triggers for my Web Jobs. I understand that just now, I will have upload my dev/test data to a real Azure Queue in another non-live Storage Container. What a bummer!